# When using type classes, how to deal with object in different ways?

Tags: scala, types, functional-programming, scalaz

Suppose I have a type class `Graph[G,V]` which states that an object of type `G` is also a graph with vertices of type `V`.

Now I have an implicit that lets me treat sets of pairs of type `A` as a graph with vertices of type `A` (not being able to express unconnected vertices...). I can use the implicit by importing the following object's scope.

```
object TupleSetGraph{
  implicit def ts2graph[A]: Graph[Set[(A,A)],A] = new Graph[Set[(A,A)],A] {
    def nodes(g: Set[(A, A)]): Set[A] = g flatMap (t => Set(t._1,t._2))
    def adjacent(g: Set[(A, A)], n1: A, n2: A): Boolean = g.contains((n1,n2)) || g.contains((n2,n1))
  }
}
```

Suppose I also want to be able to map the content of the vertices, thus being able to do the following:

```
(_: Set[(A,A)]).map((_: A => B)): Set[(B,B)]
```

But there is already a `map` defined on `Set`. How to deal with the problem that the same data structure can be seen as the same thing (something having a `map` function) in different ways?

Comment: How are you defining the type classes? As far as I understand it, you'd need to create an instance of Graph[G,V] for each class you want to make into a Graph, as in SetIsGraphable extends Graphable[Set[(V,V)], V]. But since Set is parametrized, you'd need to have an instance for every V, surely.

Comment: @Submonoid That's correct and I have added the implicit for clarification.

Comment: Have you considered that having a `Set` and then calling `map` on it and having it do something that **isn't** `Set`'s implementation of map (or a subclass implementation) would probably be a bad idea? If you want to do something different, you'll have to tell the compiler in some fashion that you want something different; the easiest way would be to just explicitly use a `Graph` rather than a `Set`.

Comment: @Ben I know that this is a problem. I want to be told some good ways to handle this dilemma.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sketching a possible solution :

### Put the map  operation in an auxiliary trait

say `GraphOps` (that could be `Graph` itself, but map signature will probably be too complex for that)

```
case class GraphOps[G](data: G) { def map...}
```

Making it easy to get the `GraphOps` :

```
object Graph {
   def apply[G](data: G) = GraphOps(data)
}
```

With that, the call will be

```
Graph(set).map(f)
```

`apply` could be made implicit, but I'm not sure I want to do that (and if I did, I'm not sure it would find map properly).

### Variant. Have the graph in GraphOps

we can also do

```
case class GraphOps[G,V](data: G, graph: Graph[G,V])
```

and

```
object Graph {
   def apply[G,V](data: G)(implicit graph: Graph[G,V]) = GraphOps(data, graph)
}
```

The good point of that is that vertex type `V` is available in GraphOps

### Defining the map operation

The signature you want is complex, with Set[(A,A)] returning a Set[(B,B)], but other graph implementations returning something completely different. This is similar to what is done in the collection library.

We may introduce a trait CanMapGraph[From, Elem, To], akin to CanBuildFrom

```
trait CanMapGrap[FromGraph, FromElem, ToGraph, ToElem] {
  def map(data: FromGraph, f: FromElem => ToElem): ToGraph
}
```

(probably you would change this to have more elementary operations than map, so that it may be used for different operations, as done with `CanBuildFrom`)

Then map would be

```
case class GraphOps[G](data: G) {
  def map[A,B](f: A, B)(implicit ev: CanMapFrom[G, A, B, G2]) : G2 =
    ev.map(data, f)
}
```

You can define

```
implicit def mapPairSetToPairSet[A, B] = 
  new CanMapGraph[Set[(A,A)], A, Set[(B,B)], B] {
    def map(set: Set[(A,A)], f: A => B) = set.map{case (x, y) => (f(x), f(y))}
  }
```

And then you do

```
val theGraph = Set("A" -> "B", "BB" -> "A", "B" -> "C", "C" -> "A")
Graph(theGraph).map(s: String -> s(0).toLower)
res1: Set[(Char, Char)] = Set((a,b), (b,a), (b,c), (c,a))
```

A problem with that is that the type of the vertices is not known in the first argument list, the one for f, so we have to be explicit with s: String.

With the alternative `GraphOps`, where we get the vertex type early, `A` is not a parameter of Map, but of `GraphOps`, so it is known from the start and does not need to be explicit in `f`. It you do it that way, you may want to pass the graph to method `map` in `CanMapGraph`.

With the first solution, it is still easy to give the graph to the `CanMapGraph`.

```
implicit def anyGraphToSet[G,V,W](implicit graph: Graph[G,V]) 
  = new CanMapFrom[G, V, Set[(W,W)], W] {
    def map(data: G, f: V => W) = 
      (for {
         from <- graph.nodes(data)
         to <- graph.nodes(data)) 
         if graph.adjacent(data, from, to) }
       yield (from, to)).toSet
  }
```

Comment: Great answer. I temporarily forgot the need for supplying builders if you want to create a modified object. So basically, the solution is to wrap the object and attach information about how the wrapped object implements the various "functions".

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> val x: Set[(A, A)] = ...
> (x: Graph[_, _]).map(...)
> ```
>
> seems to be the best you can do if you want the names to be the same.

As you point out, that's not what you want. This should work better:

```
object Graph {
  def map[G, V](graph: G)(f: V => V)(implicit instance: Graph[G, V]) = ...
}

val x: Set[(A, A)] = ...
Graph.map(x)(f) 
// but note that the type of argument of f will often need to be explicit, because
// type inference only goes from left to right, and implicit arguments come last
```

Note that you can only let `f` to be `V => V` and not `V => V1`. Why? Imagine that you have
`implicit g1: Graph[SomeType, Int]`, but not `implicit g2: Graph[SomeType, String]`. What could `Graph.map(_: SomeType)((_: Int).toString)` return then? This problem can be avoided by requiring `G` to be a parametrized type:

```
trait Graph[G[_]] {
  def nodes[A](g: G[A]): Set[A]
  def adjacent[A](g: G[A], n1: A, n2: A): Boolean
}

object TupleSetGraph{
  type SetOfPairs[A] = Set[(A,A)]
  implicit def ts2graph: Graph[SetOfPairs] = new Graph[SetOfPairs] {
    def nodes[A](g: Set[(A, A)]): Set[A] = g flatMap (t => Set(t._1,t._2))
    def adjacent[A](g: Set[(A, A)], n1: A, n2: A): Boolean = g.contains((n1,n2)) || g.contains((n2,n1))
  }
}
```

then you have

```
object Graph {
  def map[G[_], V, V1](graph: G[V])(f: V => V1)(implicit instance: Graph[G]) = ...
}
```

Comment: But `Graph` is a type class and `x` is not converted into one.

Comment: This works and I like your suggestion of making `G` parameterized. But what I cannot obtain is to use all the functions provided by Scalaz by simply giving evidence that a graph is pointed; and it provides a map and so on. I see that this cannot work somehow because there are already implicit type class objects provided for Set. But I'd like to receive input on how I can work around this problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using type classes, then you can do something like this:

```
implicitly[TypeClass].map(...)
```

If you are using view bounds, then Alexey's answer is correct:

```
(...: ViewBound).map(...)
```